# Unable to open X display with python subprocess and DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY variables set

Tags: python, x11, systemd

I'm trying to launch a message box from a python systemd service which is running as root.

```
subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/zenity", "--info", "--text", "please reboot for changes to take effect"], env=dict(os.environ, DISPLAY="0.0", XAUTHORITY="/home/pi/.Xauthority"))
```

I've set the environment variable DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY however I still get a connection refused message

```
** (zenity:5491): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Unable to init sever: Could not connect: Connection refused
(zenity:5491): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 0.0
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Could you try DISPLAY = ":0.0"?

Comment: yup, working now - pretty dumb mistake. Cheers

Comment: Most excellent :D

Comment: @BoboDarph would you post that suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely due to incorrect value in DISPLAY env var. Try DISPLAY = ":0.0"

```
subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/zenity", "--info", "--text", "please reboot for changes to take effect"], env=dict(os.environ, DISPLAY=":0.0", XAUTHORITY="/home/pi/.Xauthority"))
```